# Weird boolean evaluation in python 3.8

Tags: python

While trying to debug an issue, I hit some weird boolean evaluation happening in python. Below is the sample shell result.

```
In [4]: True or False and False
Out[4]: True

In [5]: False or True and False
Out[5]: False
```

What exactly is happening here. Shouldn't both evaluate to the same result?

Comment: No, it's behaving according to the rules of boolean logic. Look into precedence to understand why.

Comment: 'and` binds tighter than `or`.  The first expression is `True or False` which is True.  The second expression is `False or False`, which is False.  https://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I actually ended up confusing myself between the left to right evaluation, and precedence of boolean operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`and` binds tighter than `or`, so what you're writing is actually

```
In [4]: True or (False and False)
Out[4]: True

In [5]: False or (True and False)
Out[5]: False
```

Answer (score 3):

`and` takes precedence over `or`. See what happens when we evaluate the `and` first?

```py
>>> (True or False and False) == (True or False)
True
>>> (False or True and False) == (False or False)
True
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [python order of precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) **AND** has higher precedence than **OR** hence **AND** will get evaluated first followed by **OR**.

So it evaluates to something like below

```
(True or (False and False)) = True
(False or (True and False)) = False
```